# Google Sign In Button does Nothing

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I have implemented the Google Sign In exactly as Google states to according to their website. I had it working about a month ago, now it just does nothing. I tried to redo everything by deleting the cocoapod and following their website to a T but nothing is happening still. It is like none of the delegate methods are being called, and I am unsure why. Any help would be appreciative. Thanks!

```
import GoogleSignIn
import Google
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //Get Twitter and set Twitter keys for Application
    Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey("uBedaxDuMDgImGbjun1oYf0ay", consumerSecret: "OaKqBZUesX5CypHCwrTvTZE22jrXIuRsUeZzVaMHej11R5Vh3b")
    Fabric.with([Twitter.self])

    // Initialize sign-in GOOGLE
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                                                annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var options: [String: AnyObject] = [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey: sourceApplication!,
                                        UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey: annotation!]
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                annotation: annotation)
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {
    print("SIGNING IN")
    if (error == nil) {
        let email = user.profile.email
        print(user.authentication)
        // ...
    } else {
        print("ERROR = \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

View Controller

```
import GoogleSignIn
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    //Default setup for View Controller
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    var error:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&error)
    if(error != nil) {
        print(error)
    }

    var signInButton = GIDSignInButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 400))
    view.addSubview(signInButton)

}
```

**EDIT**

After HOURS, lol, of figuring this out, the Google Sign-In Button works when it is 
1)Held down for more than 2 seconds, 
2)Swiped left/down/right but not up
I am unsure of this cause and would be open to suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: There you go. Thanks for looking

Comment: This was the issue for me. Resolved by pressing the button for 2 seconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have figured it out, would like to let anyone else know this stupid stupid issue!

The problem is with the Google button and the tap I have to dismiss the keyboard.
I didn't put it on here, but here it is.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.dismissKeyboard))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func dismissKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Google's Delegates mess this up for some reason. I haven't come up with a solution yet, as I literally just now found the issue, but if anyone else has an issue, I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I think I'm experiencing the same problem. I got it to work and then all of a sudden it stopped working.

When I remove "GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self" this line of code it breaks, and when I pop it back I get no errors but absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: Well my issue is: I had a google sign in button and on top of that, I had added a tap gesture to the entire view. So it would register the tap gesture instead of the google button. So if I held down longer on the google button, then the tap wouldnt register but the google button would. So I had to find a way to register a tap on the screen(that allowed the keyboard to hide if it was there) and use the GID button.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and that was a problem with a tap gesture recognizer that was bound to the main view in order to dismiss keyboard. It was accidentally capturing also the touches inside the GIDSignInButton. Changing this setting helped:

```
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Comment: This is the trick! You literally saved me.
Best answer even after 17 months

Answer (score 7):

**Quick, Easy Solution:**

Steps:

1. Extend to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`
2. Paste in the following methods
3. add `dismissOnTap()` to your view controller

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Call dismissOnTap
        dismissOnTap()

 }

 func dismissOnTap() {
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("dismissKeyboard"))
        tap.delegate = self
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
 }

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view is GIDSignInButton {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Implement your UITapGestureRecognizer's delegate and handle the case you tapped on your Google sign in button:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view is GIDSignInButton {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Swift 3:

```
  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
   if touch.view is GIDSignInButton {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

since my button not working properly i used to put a UIButton over the GIDSignInButton and called the method inside my UIButton action which made all good

```
@IBAction func signInWithGoogle(_ sender: Any) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution was very simple. Just do this:

use .allTouchEvents

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleGoogleLogin), for: .allTouchEvents)