# IOS- Google sign in button

Tags: ios, swift, button, authentication, google-signin

in my app I have my google sign in button which works well but I have a problem clicking this button. It goes on only if I click on the button about 3 seconds. I would tap on the button and go directly to the permission page or to another activity. 
Thank you in advance for your help.

**AppDelegate:**

```
import GoogleSignIn

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FIRApp.configure()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true

    }

    func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
        withError error: NSError!) {
            if (error == nil) {
                // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
                let userId = user.userID // For client-side use only!
                let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
                let fullName = user.profile.name
                let givenName = user.profile.givenName
                let familyName = user.profile.familyName
                let email = user.profile.email
                // ...
            } else {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
        withError error: NSError!) {
            // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
            // ...
    }

}
```

**Login:**

```
    import GoogleSignIn

    class Login: UIViewController,GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var google_view: UIView!
        let login_button_google = GIDSignInButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

hideKeyboard()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")

        login_button_google.center = self.google_view.center
        self.view!.addSubview(login_button_google)

    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
        withError error: NSError!) {

        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            userId = user.userID // For client-side use only!
            idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            fullName = user.profile.name
            email = user.profile.email
            performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToDoing", sender: nil)

        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem thanks to:

[Google Sign In Button does Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741890/google-sign-in-button-does-nothing?rq=1)

If someone have a problem with google sign in button it is probably some delegate element. In my case the problem is the uiviewcontroller extension with my hideKeyboard() in **viewDidLoad** method.