# Flutter firebase auth throwing platform exception not being caught by try catch

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, firebase-authentication

Im running into this issue and im not sure why. I have everything set up on firebase and everything works fine for signup up and signin when you type the username/pass correctly. However, when trying to catch error, im getting a platform exception and its in a wierd form. (This is me trying an incorrect password). As you can see theres a Firebaseauthexception inside a Platform Exception inside a platform exception and my try catch isnt even able to catch it. Im updated to the most recent version of ^1.1.1

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(firebase_auth, com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password., {code: wrong-password, additionalData: {}, message: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.}, null))
```

```
try {
    userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: user, password: pass);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
      print('No user found for that email.');
    } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
      print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
    }
  }
```

UPDATE im also getting this displayed:

```
Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

UPDATE 2
found this link which describes what im having similarly
[Google Sign-In With Flutter: Error Code -4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132892/google-sign-in-with-flutter-error-code-4)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use `on PlatformException`, see what happens.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad No change. I also tried using .onError, Im still getting an error but its one from the firebase files. Not sure why, after I skip forward with the arrow, I get it to say the error code but its still not being caught by the try catch or onError

Comment: HI, did you find the solution for your problem